# What does 辞書形＋といけない mean?

Tags: grammar

Usually といけない follows ない形 of 辞書形.
For example,

- 寝る前に、歯を磨かないといけない。I have to brush my teeth before sleeping.
- 明日までに宿題を出さないといけない。I have to hand in my homework by tomorrow.

Today, I read a new grammar 辞書形＋といけない. I really don't know what this grammar mean. For example,

- 風邪を引くといけないから、暖かい服を着たほうがいい。
- 子供が寂しがるといけないと思って、おもちゃで遊ばせておきました。
- 子供に言い過ぎるといけないと思うが、すぐ口を出してしまう。

The book also provides other but similar meanings for each sentence above as follows.

- ～引いてはから～ is equal to ～引くといけないから～
- ～寂しがってはと思って～ is equal to ～寂しがるといけないと思って～
- ～言い過ぎてはと思うが～ is equal to ～言い過ぎるといけないと思うが～

Any comments and suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: I think 引いてはから is a typo for something, but was not sure what the original sentence was like. Could you check that part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that what is important to see here is that the と here is the conditional-と.

> - 歯を磨かないと…if you don't brush your teeth
> - 風邪を引くと…if you catch a cold

Next step is to understand the いけない part. You can see it as *won't go (well)* in the meaning of *not good*.

> - 歯を磨かないといけない…if you don't brush your teeth, that'll be not good. (Hence the meaning of: you **must** brush your teeth.)
> - 風邪を引くといけないから、暖かい服を着たほうがいい。…because if you catch a cold it will be *no good*, you'd better wear a warm piece of clothing. (Hence, you should wear a warm piece of clothing because you don't want to end up catching a cold.)

---

Here ては is a shortened version of てはだめだ・てはいけない・てはならない. Again, ては indicates conditional.

So 引いては~から　≒　引いてはいけない　≒　引くといけない

Comment: I ran a quick search and I could not find anything on ては being used as a conditional (that could be a question to ask). But you can find this same ては in てはどうか？ (読んでみてはどうか -- what about reading it?) [[also ては is used as a conditional in 古文 even if it may not be relevant here]].