# Meaning of てなきゃ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form, transitivity

While playing a Japanese mobile horror game, a girl appears with a knife in hand and says the following:

> 「おとなしくしてなきゃダメじゃない」

I can guess this probably means something like *It's a problem if you don't stay quiet, isn't it?* but I have problem parsing the てなきゃ: is it from してある (state), as in ドアをあけてあった?

Is the "transitive verb"てある grammar at work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

してなきゃ is していなければ, and it's the result of these three contractions:

1. していなければ → してなければ (`-inai` to `-nai` / `-iru` to `-ru` / `-imasu` to `-masu`, discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12802/5010))
2. してなければ → してなけりゃ (`-eba` to `-ya` contraction, discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010))
3. してなけりゃ → してなきゃ (`-erya` to `-ya` contraction, discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010))

～なければだめ, ～ないとだめ, ～なければいけない and so on are very common double-negative construction. These literally mean "if not then it's not good", but usually you can translate them just as "must" or "have to".

- [What does 辞書形＋といけない mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33384/5010)
- [Help me to understand やらなきゃいけない and やらなきゃならない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42861/5010)

じゃない at the end adds "..., okay?", "..., right?" or "..., you know?" feeling to the sentence.

- [「～たじゃない」 expression in spoken Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/453/5010)

So the whole sentence means "You have to stay calm, okay?", "You must keep quiet, you know?", etc.